# How do I get all of one key from a list of dicts in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a large JSON file like so:

```
{
  "data" : [
    {"album": "I Look to You", "writer": "Leon Russell", "artist": "Whitney Houston", "year": "2009", "title": "\"A Song for You\""},
    {"album": "Michael Zager Band", "writer": "Michael Zager", "artist": "Whitney Houston", "year": "1983", "title": "\"Life's a Party\""},
    {"album": "Paul Jabara & Friends", "writer": "Paul Jabara", "artist": "Whitney Houston", "year": "1978", "title": "\"Eternal Love\""},
    ...
```

...and I'm trying to make a very simple API to get the different values.  Right now I can fairly easily get `localhost/data/1/title` for example to get that first title value, but I want to get *all* of the titles by doing `localhost/titles` or something.  How would I modify the `do_GET` method here to do add that sort of functionality?

```
def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
    self.end_headers()

    path = self.path[1:]
    components = string.split(path, '/')

    node = content
    for component in components:
        if len(component) == 0 or component == "favicon.ico":
            continue

        if type(node) == dict:
            node = node[component]

        elif type(node) == list:
            node = node[int(component)]

    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(node))

    return
```

Comment: Did you try python's json module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html This might be helpful.

Comment: @HaochenWu, I think she is already using that module.

Comment: Oh, I see. You have dumps in your code. Then what's wrong with loads function? It should return you an object with all the structures in you json file. You can start from that and it should be easy to iterate over. Sorry I probably still don't get your question here.

Comment: Your do_GET function seems to be some web applications, but without more context it's hard to see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer that will follow your current dynamic URL patterns without major architectural changes or requirements.

Here, I'm using  "all" in replace of a given numeric index in your url pattern, as I feel this better represents your paradigm of `data/[item(s)]/[attribute]`

Following are some URLs and example output:

1. `/data/1/album` => "Michael Zager Band"
2. `/data/0/title` => "A Song for You"
3. `/data/all/title` => ["A Song for You", "Life's a Party", "Eternal Love"]
4. `/data/all/year` => ["2009", "1983", "1978"]
5. `/data/1` => {"album": "Michael Zager Band", "title": "Life's a Party", "writer": "Michael Zager", "year": "1983", "artist": "Whitney Houston"}

PS - I changed the architecture a little, to use recursion, which I think better follows what you're looking to do.

```
def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
    self.end_headers()

    path = self.path[1:]
    components = string.split(path, '/')

    node = parse_node(content, components)

    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(node))

    return

def parse_node(node, components):
    # For a valid node and component list:
    if node and len(components) and components[0] != "favicon.ico":
        # Dicts will return parse_node of the top-level node component found, 
        # reducing the component list by 1
        if type(node) == dict:
            return parse_node(node.get(components[0], None), components[1:])

        elif type(node) == list:
            # A list with an "all" argument will return a full list of sub-nodes matching the rest of the URL criteria
            if components[0] == "all":
                return [parse_node(n, components[1:]) for n in node]
            # A normal list node request will work as it did previously
            else:
                return parse_node(node[int(components[0])], components[1:])
    else:
        return node

    # Handle bad URL
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running into trouble because you're trying to loop over the path components to determine what to do. This is a somewhat complicated way of solving the problem.

I would first define the "routes" or "actions" you want your API to support, then write code to handle each of those. This is how most web frameworks operate (e.g. [django's URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#example) or [flask's routes](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#url-route-registrations)). It's pretty simple to use this same pattern in your code.

So, from your description it sounds like you want two routes:

```
/data/{id}/{attr} - look up the value of `attr` for the given `id`
/{attr} - search all items for `attr`
```

I'm also going to simplify "title" vs. "titles" and just use the singular form, since pluralization is probably going to be more trouble than it's worth. But if you really want to do it, there are libraries that can help (e.g. [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect)).

Once we decide the URLs are going to follow those two patterns, it's easy to check if the components match against those. Note, I've simplified your code here to get it running because I'm not sure how `do_GET` is called, or what `self` is:

```
import json

JSON = {
    "data" : [
        {"album": "I Look to You", "writer": "Leon Russell", "artist": "Whitney Houston", "year": "2009", "title": "\"A Song for You\""},
        {"album": "Michael Zager Band", "writer": "Michael Zager", "artist": "Whitney Houston", "year": "1983", "title": "\"Life's a Party\""},
        {"album": "Paul Jabara & Friends", "writer": "Paul Jabara", "artist": "Whitney Houston", "year": "1978", "title": "\"Eternal Love\""},
    ]
}

def do_GET(path):
    path = path[1:]
    components = path.split('/')

    if components[0] == 'favicon.ico':
        return "favicon response"
    elif len(components) == 0 or not path:
        return "error response"
    elif len(components) == 3 and components[0] == "data":
        #/data/{id}/{attr} - look up the value of `attr` for the given `id`
        key, item_id, attr = components
        item_id = int(item_id)
        return json.dumps(JSON[key][item_id][attr])
    elif len(components) == 1:
        #/{attr} - search all items for `attr`
        attr = components[0]
        out = []
        for k in JSON:
            for d in JSON[k]:
                if attr in d:
                    out.append(d[attr])
        return json.dumps(out)
    else:
        return "unknown response"

    return json.dumps(node)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = [
        "/data/1/title",
        "/title",
        "/some_missing_attr",
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/",
    ]
    for u in urls:
        print u, "->", do_GET(u)
```

Output:

```
/data/1/title -> "\"Life's a Party\""
/title -> ["\"A Song for You\"", "\"Life's a Party\"", "\"Eternal Love\""]
/some_missing_attr -> []
/favicon.ico -> favicon response
/ -> error response
```

This should work well unless you really do want to do arbitrary nested lookups inside arbitrary JSON. If that's the case then I don't think the URLs you proposed will work, how would you know that "/titles" should search all elements and "/data" would look up one element? If you really want to do that, I would search google for "JSON query language" and see what projects you could re-use or gain ideas from.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague idea but I hope the concept is understood.

In this example, if the url does not start with 'data', it will map the data collection with the component specified in the url (like 'titles').

```
def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
    self.end_headers()

    path = self.path[1:]
    components = string.split(path, '/')

    if components and components[0] != 'data':
        node = map(lambda x: x.get(components[0]), content)
    else:
        node = content
        for component in components:
            if len(component) == 0 or component == "favicon.ico":
                continue

            if type(node) == dict:
                node = node[component]

            elif type(node) == list:
                node = node[int(component)]

    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(node))

    return
```